# How to fix form validation in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to build a contact form that uses ajax and PHP to send a mail. ajax, and email submission is working fine but PHP validation is not working and I receive unfiltered user credentials in my email box at the server, here is the code please help the php validation is not working and any data a user enters in the form is not filtered and is send the way it is.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('includes/db_connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] && isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] && isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] && isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message']){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);

    if(( !preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/",$name))||(strlen($name) < 3)){
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'invalid name'));
    }else{
        $name_error = "";
    }
    if((!is_numeric($phone))||(strlen($phone) !=12)){
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'invalid phone'));
    }else{
        $phone_error = "";
    }
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'invalid email'));
    }else{
        $email_error = "";
    }
    if(strlen($message)<10){
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'invalid message'));
    }else{
        $message_error = "";
    }

    if(empty($name_error) && empty($phone_error) && empty($email_error)&& empty($message_error)){

        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT);

        ini_set("include_path", '/home/extensiv/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );
        require_once "Mail.php";

        $host = "ssl://mail.mywebsite.com";
        $username = "support@mywebsite.com";
        $password = "mypassword";
        $port = "465";
        $to = "support@mywebsite.com";
        $email_from = $email;
        $email_subject = "Is it working?: " ;
        $email_body = $message.$phone ;
        $email_address = "support@mywebsite.com";

        $headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);


        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo json_encode(array('success' => 'submit error'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('success' => 'submit success'));
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('success' => 'invalid credentials'));
    }    
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>'No data received'));
}
?>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: BTW: the whole line `if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] && isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] && isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] && isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message']){` can be replaced with 1 isset(....) .... take a look at the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) .... why is a name with 2 characters not valid? (e.g. Lu) ... also why does a phone number have to have 12 digits? ... also don't forget to turn off `error_reporting` in the production mode

Comment: ___is not working___ That is not a very useful description of any issue. Please tell us WHICH part of the code is not working, then tell us what you expect it to do.

Comment: `$name_error` etc... is always empty! You never assign anything to them you just echo JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You never set $name_error, $phone_error, $email_error or $message_error to any value. 
Your condition will always be true as $name_error (and the others) will all be null. Empty returns true when null.

To fix, set the $name_error (and the others) to the error string then echo it from the string.

```
if(( !preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/",$name))||(strlen($name) < 3)){
    $name_error = json_encode(array('success' => 'invalid name'));
    echo $name_error;
}else{
    $name_error = "";
}
```

I also suggest adding a die() after your first error. Otherwise you can end up with a return payload containing multiple json objects.